# How to create output filename with given name in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I have library that use ES modules and I want to generate UMD file in ES5. I have config like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve('./src/index.js')
    },
    output: {
        library: 'name',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'umd.min.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

and webpack create file `main.js` how can I make output file `umd.min.js`?

```
> webpack --mode production

Hash: 98ccf0949bfdf066246a
Version: webpack 4.44.0
Time: 97ms
Built at: 25.07.2020 16:30:31
  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  2.23 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js + 3 modules 3.6 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./src/index.js 294 bytes [built]
    | ./src/Canvas.js 1.88 KiB [built]
    | ./src/Item.js 1.2 KiB [built]
    | ./src/constants.js 239 bytes [built]
```

My package.json look like this:

```
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "unpkg": "./dist/umd.min.js",
```

So this a bug? Why the file name is main.js?

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using? I'm aware of `loaders` is no longer existed to be replaced by `rules` instead. To be honest I don't see anything weird in your configuration though.

Comment: @tmhao2005 the config was wrong, but it didn't matter it was not loaded at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that webpack-cli suggest to rename the file to cjs but don't say that it's not loaded by default, you need to explicitly add --config with  the filename when running webpack.

See this issue:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1165

Answer (score 4):

So, by default the webpack emits the chunk name as "main.js", so if you want to rename the chunk name, use the "chunkFilename" option in the output object of  your webpack config file, here is the example how i did that:

```
output: {
filename: env === 'development' ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js',
path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
chunkFilename: 'scripts/[name].[hash].js',},
```

in your case you should do:

```
chunkFilename: 'umd.min.js'
```

Comment: Filename works, the config was not loaded. You don't need `chunkFilename`